# $X$ is finitely generated as a module over $A$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

$A,B$ are $k$-algebras and finitely generated as $k$-modules. Let $X$ be a simple $A \otimes_k B$ module. Since $A \otimes_k B$ is finitely generated as a $k$-module, $X$ is finitely generated as a $k$-module, hence also as a module over $A$ via the canonical map $A \to A \otimes_k B$.

I am not sure how to see that  $X$ is finitely generated as a module over $A$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume $k$ is a field?

If so, everything in sight is a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$;
each of $A$ and $B$ are and so is $A\otimes_k B$; also $X$ as a quotient
of $A\otimes_k B$ is too.

As $X$ is finite-dimensional over $k$, it has a $k$-basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.
Then also $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ generate $X$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: Hello Angina! Sorry, I didn't make it clear. $k$ is a commutative ring... But it won't affect much, I think!

Comment: The important thing is that $X$ is a **quotient** of $A\otimes B$ so even if $k$ is non-Noetherian then $X$ is finitely generated over $k$.